# RDP over Citrix Receiver is sluggish

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, citrix-receiver

I am using Citrix Receiver to connect to a workstation remotely on a fiber-backed 100 Mb UP / 100 Mb Down connection.  I believe there is more than sufficient bandwidth; however, there is significant mouse lag that makes it frustrating to use.

I have monitored the traffic and do not see any packet loss or re-transmissions.

The remote machine is running Windows 10 and has all of the fancy UI settings disabled.

What can I do on either end to make the experience better?  Additionally, I am assuming the problem must be on my end, either the ISP is putting the traffic into a large buffer where the latency is introduced, or my hardware is problematic and I have yet to spot the problem.

Additionally, when monitoring the bandwidth on my gateway, I am using < 1Mb / s (through the entire pipe) and < 100kb / s to the remote desktop machine.

Comment: Do you get the same lag in the Windows RDP client (mstsc.exe)?

Comment: I have no option, I have to use Citrix Receiver when remote (over VPN).  If I am in the local network, then it is quick.  I'm trying to isolate the problem as on my end or the gateway (Citrix).